# How to use controller content into view.js in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to pass input value from one view to  another like this

#### Firstview

```
oFooter.addContent(new sap.m.Button("b1", {
        text   : "Execute",
        icon   : "sap-icon://display",
        styled : false,
        press  : function() {        
            var In_obj = sap.ui.getCore().byId('inobj').getValue();
            var Ins_obj = sap.ui.getCore().byId('insobj').getValue();
            var In_exid = sap.ui.getCore().byId('exid').getValue();
            var In_dp1 = sap.ui.getCore().byId('DP1').getValue();
            var In_dp2 = sap.ui.getCore().byId('DP2').getValue();
            var In_usr = sap.ui.getCore().byId('User').getValue();
            var In_tcd = sap.ui.getCore().byId('tcode').getValue();
            var In_prg = sap.ui.getCore().byId('prog').getValue();

            app.to("page2", {
                Input_obj : In_obj,
                Input_sobj : Ins_obj,
                Input_exid : In_exid,
                Input_dp1 : In_dp1,
                Input_dp2 : In_dp2,
                Input_usr : In_usr,
                Input_tcd : In_tcd,
                Input_prg : In_prg,
            });

        }
    }));
```

#### `Secondview.controller.js`

```
onInit : function() {
                     alert("second page init"  );
                      view.addEventDelegate({
                      onBeforeShow: function(evt) {

                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_obj;
                      Input_obj = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_sobj;
                      Input_sobj = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_exid;
                      Input_exid = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_dp1;
                      Input_dp1 = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_dp2;
                      Input_dp2 = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_usr;
                      Input_usr = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_tcd;
                      Input_tcd = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.Input_prg;
                      Input_prg = idToRetrieve.getValue();
                      alert( Input_obj );
                      console.log( Input_obj);
                    }});
                },
```

Now, I don't know how to use variables (`Input_obj`, `Input_sobj`, ...) in `Secondview.js(view)`. Can I have some guidance about this ?

Comment: I didn't tried on my own but you can try to use the event bus of the framework. Please have a read here https://scn.sap.com/thread/3309881 there are also other places where this topic is discuseed. Hope this helps

Comment: http://www.bpse.com.au/blog/89

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see in your code idToRetrieve should have the value(text) of the the element with ID inobj.
You are passing the dataobj while calling the app.to method and therefore in the onbeforeshow method the data should be available.

There is a concept of routes in SAPUI5 specifically which can also be used here 
[Routing](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/68/8f36bd758e4ce2b4e682eef4dc794e/content.htm)

But with the current approach as well i can see the data should be available in the onbeforeshow method

For Example

```
app.to("detailPage", {id:"42"}); // trigger navigation and hand over a data object
                                 // this data object could also be a binding context when dealing with data binding
...


// and where the detail page is implemented:
myDetailPage.addEventDelegate({
   onBeforeShow: function(evt) {
      var idToRetrieve = evt.data.id;
      // ...now retrieve the data element with the given ID and update the page UI
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi Veeraraghavan thanks for suggestion. Yes data are available in the onbeforeshow method but i want to use it in relative view.js like Secondview.controller.js   to     Secondview.view.js

Comment: Then i would suggest you use Event buses. Typically an event bus is where you trigger an event and the view would subscribe to the event. You can also pass the data to the event and the the view can receive the data